# Exception while Disposing Camera before initialization is ready

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I use a code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
while

I've got exception when i push back button but camera is not Initialized.

An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in Microsoft.Devices.Camera.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

How to avoid exception?
The problem with:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_photoCamera != null )
            {
                // Dispose camera to minimize power consumption and to expedite shutdown.
                _photoCamera.Dispose();                            


                _photoCamera.Initialized -= cam_Initialized;
                _photoCamera.AutoFocusCompleted -= _photoCamera_AutoFocusCompleted;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try making sure that the `Dispose` method is the last one you call on `_photoCamera` (i.e. don't modify the events `.Initalized` and `.AutoFocusCompleted` after `.Dispose`)

Comment: I've done as You said but I have UnhandledException and I do not where it accurs.  I have the same problem like in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/97f9649d-f29a-4993-8883-9b5ba0bc2f81/photocamera-dispose-exception